# How to count # comparisons and swaps made for heapsort?

Tags: java, sorting, heapsort

I am trying to figure out where the incrementers for comparisons and moves made are placed in my heap sort algorithm. Comparisons are when two integers are being assess and not necessarily have to be moved. Moves are when a value in the array switches with another. So a successful swap will be 2 moves.

```
   public static void heapSort( int [] a )
{
    for( int i = a.length / 2; i >= 0; i-- )  /* buildHeap */
        percDown( a, i, a.length );
    for( int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i-- )
    {
        swapReferences( a, 0, i );            /* deleteMax */
        percDown( a, 0, i );
    }
}

/**
 * Internal method for heapsort.
 * @param i the index of an item in the heap.
 * @return the index of the left child.
 */
private static int leftChild( int i )
{
    return 2 * i + 1;
}
/**
 * Internal method for heapsort that is used in
 * deleteMax and buildHeap.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 * @index i the position from which to percolate down.
 * @int n the logical size of the binary heap.
 */
private static void percDown( int[] a, int i, int n )
{
    int child;
    int tmp;

    for( tmp = a[i]; leftChild( i ) < n; i = child )
    {
        child = leftChild( i );
        if( child != n - 1 && a[child] < a[child + 1] )
            child++;
        if( tmp < a[child])
            a[ i ] = a[ child ];
        else
            break;
    }
    a[ i ] = tmp;
}


/**
 * Method to swap to elements in an array.
 * @param a an array of objects.
 * @param index1 the index of the first object.
 * @param index2 the index of the second object.
 */
public static final void swapReferences( int [ ] a, int index1, int index2 )
{
    int tmp = a[ index1 ];
    a[ index1 ] = a[ index2 ];
    a[ index2 ] = tmp;
}
```

Please use `numMoves` and `numCompares`as the variable names for them.

Answer (score 0):

Moves: increment numMoves in your swapReferences method.

Compares: increment numCompares in percDown where the the compare operators are being used.